# Single line comment - unable to compile on solaris

Tags: c, solaris

I'm trying to compile a C program on Solaris. It's complaining on lines having comments starting with `//`.

I'm new to solaris. Please suggest a solution.

ss0iconv.c

```
// This is line 193
```

Output:

```
src/c_asm/sol/ss0iconv.c", line 193: syntax error before or at: /
```

Answer (score 11):

The // style comments were introduced in C99 - your compiler probably only supports C89, so you won't be able to use them.

Comment: @novice2010in It's not a compiler version, it the version of the C Standard. You need to read your compiler's docs to see what it supports.